# How can I have the total time Psychopy

Tags: psychopy

I made an experimentation on Psychopy. I have Intructions, 10 differents routines and then msg end.

I am able to have all the time it took for each routine, but I will like to have the total time of my 10 routines without having to calculate it my self in my csv file at the end.

Code for having my duration of each trial. I putted this line in each routine.

```
thisExp.addData('trial_duration1', t)
```

I tried to create a variable total and adding all the trial_duration, but my column was empty in the csv file at the end.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Psychopy has an internal clock which starts when the experiment starts. You can read the time using `core.monotonicClock.getTime()`. The timing of this clock starts almost immediately as you hit "run", i.e. before the dialogue box, so it doesn't read the time since the first routine started. However, you can get that duration by first recording the time of the clock in a code component when you want time zero to be defined:

```py
time_zero = core.monotonicClock.getTime()
```

... and then record the time elapsed doing

```py
thisExp.addData('cumulative_duration', core.monotonicClock.getTime() - time_zero)
```

Note that if you want to do this only for particular loops (e.g. define `time_zero` in the first loop and record `cumulative_duration` in the last loop) require the condition to be satisfied:

```py
# If this is the first iteration of the loop (no matter the name of the loop)
if currentLoop.thisN == 0:
    time_zero = core.monotonicClock.getTime()
```